# JavaScript code not causing image to reappear when scrolling back up

Tags: javascript

I have an image that I want to disappear if the user scrolls further than `1000px` down the window. I want that same image to reappear if the user turns around and scrolls back up. I have written the following JavaScript. This code currently makes the image disappear, but it does not have the image display again if you scroll back up. That is what I want, but this code only changes the `display` to `"none"`. Can someone help? Thanks!

```
function parallex () {
    var ypos = window.pageYOffset; 
    var image = document.getElementById('section_1'); 
    image.style.top = ypos * -.2 + "px"; 

    if (ypos > 1000){
        image = document.getElementById('section_1'); 
        image.style.display = "none"; 
    }
    else {
        image.style.display = "visible";
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', parallex);
```

Comment: `display="block"`, not `visible`

Comment: Also, you can remove the duplicate `image = document.getElementById('section_1');` that's under `if (ypos > 1000){`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be setting `display` to `''` (the empty string) <del>`initial`</del>, not `visible`, in your scroll handler.

**Edit:** It looks like IE does not support the `initial` keyword, so I would recommend using either the empty string (as I have) or `display: block` (as advised by [Josiah Keller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3900404/josiah-keller) in the comments above).

I would also suggest using the ternary operator (`condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse`) to set the `display` property in a single line of code.

```js
function parallex () {
  var y = window.pageYOffset
  var image = document.getElementById('section_1')
  
  image.style.top = y * -.2 + 'px'
  image.style.display = y > 1000 ? 'none' : ''
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', parallex)
```

```css
body { height: 3000px; }
```

```html
<img id="section_1" src="http://www.placehold.it/350x1100" />
```